# C - select() on stdin when there is already data in stdin's buffer

Tags: c, linux, select, posix

> The select function blocks the calling process until there is activity on any of the specified sets of file descriptors [...] A file descriptor is considered ready for reading if a read call will not block. (See: https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Waiting-for-I_002fO.html)

So I expected, that select in the following program would immediately return in the 2nd, ... iteration, if you enter a string > 4 characters in the first iteration. However it does not. Just after pressing any other key after the first output it continues to handle all the remaining input. Why?

Sample output:

```
./selectTest
12345678900
Keyboard input received: 1234
A
Keyboard input received: 5678
Keyboard input received: 900

Keyboard input received: A
```

Code

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>

int main(void)
{
    fd_set rfds;
    char buf[100];

    while(1)
    {
        FD_ZERO(&rfds);       
        FD_SET(fileno(stdin), &rfds);

        if(-1 == select(FD_SETSIZE, &rfds, NULL, NULL, NULL))
        {
            perror("select() failed\n");
        }

        if(FD_ISSET(fileno(stdin), &rfds)) 
        {
            printf("Keyboard input received: ");
            fgets(buf, 5, stdin);
            printf("%s\n", buf);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

(I know, that I should not use select() anymore, but I am learning for an exam and we have to ...)

Comment: What is your problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are reading from a [tty(4)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man4/tty.4.html) (in the usual case when *stdin* is your terminal). These are tricky things, read the [tty demystified](http://www.linusakesson.net/programming/tty/).

Be aware that your terminal and its tty has some [line discipline](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_discipline). So, some data is buffered in the kernel (and also in the standard library).

You might want to put your tty in raw mode. See [termios(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/termios.3.html) & [stty(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ssty.1.html)

But don't lose your time, instead use some library like [ncurses](http://www.gnu.org/s/ncurses/) or [readline](http://www.gnu.org/s/readline)

To play with `select`, you might use some [fifo(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/fifo.7.html), perhaps with `mkfifo /tmp/myfifo` then `yourprogram < /tmp/myfifo` and, in another terminal, `echo hello > /tmp/myfifo`

Answer (score 4):

Fundamentally, the problem is that you're mixing buffered stdio streams with low-level I/O. The reason the `select` is blocking is because the previously typed data has already been read and is buffered in `stdin`'s stream data buffer. Try setting `stdin` to unbuffered mode by calling `setbuf(stdin, NULL)`.

Comment: This is true, but probably not the only reason for the problem.

Comment: Adding a call to `setbuf(stdin, NULL);` before the `while` loop seems to fix it though. Well, "fix it" apart from the lack of end-of-file detection, but that's a separate issue!