# Timeout for blocking function call, i.e., how to stop waiting for user input after X seconds?

Tags: c++, io, timeout

When asking the user for input we need to call a blocking function, but I want to be able to "unblock" and resume after a specified timeout has elapsed (usually some seconds).

How can I do this?

```
std::string s;
// blocking function call
std::cin >> s; // how can I resume operation after timeout duration has elapsed?
```

Comment: For `std::cin` specifically: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18552029/how-to-make-reading-from-stdcin-timeout-after-a-particular-amount-of-time https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9053175/is-it-possible-to-set-timeout-for-stdcin https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18589140/making-auto-timeout-with-stdcin-statement

Comment: It is not the compiler that is waiting. It is your compiled executable.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot do the way you dream, at least not in *standard* C++11 (using only standardized C++11 functions). You practically need some [operating system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operating_system) support, and you implicitly want some [event loop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_loop) (or use some multi-[threading](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_%28computing%29) approach).

However, you could use your operating system facilities and/or some external libraries.

FWIW, Linux has multiplexing [syscalls](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_call) such as [poll(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html) (and I am sure that Windows, Android, MacOSX, .... have similar things); but you'll much better use libraries like [ncurses](https://www.gnu.org/software/ncurses/ncurses.html) or [Qt](http://qt.io/) or [SFML](http://www.sfml-dev.org/) (see also [POCO](http://pocoproject.org/) framework).

Details are considerably more complex than what you imagine, and are operating system specific (but some libraries are frameworks working on several operating systems). See also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33887959/841108) & [that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34068150/841108) answers and read the [tty demystified](http://www.linusakesson.net/programming/tty/) page. Be aware that "[terminal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_terminal)" is usually today some abstract virtual device, but in the past have been a complex device (which is mostly emulated today).

And don't forget that `cin` might be something else than a terminal. It might be (on POSIX systems notably) a [pipe(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/pipe.7.html) (command [pipeline](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pipeline_%28Unix%29)) or a file ([redirection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Redirection_%28computing%29)). Then waiting for 5 seconds might be meaningless or useless.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a program with `main()` which creates 2 processes say `process1()` and `process2()` using `fork()` function.

In `process1()` take Input form user.

In `process2()` make a delay of `X` seconds as you say and then terminate the process1 via process2.