# How to call a function in a for loop?

Tags: c++

I have tried to use the getch() function to meet my requirement but it did not work.
What am I supposed to do if I want to call a function in an infinite for loop only when I press some key otherwise the loop keeps on running without calling the function?

Comment: How long is the duration of a keypress? As a keypress can span several loop cycles...

Comment: Please post some code so we have a reference point to work from.

Comment: Your (too broad) question is very similar to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/34108024/841108) one, and [my](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34108064/841108) answer should be relevant here.

Comment: Do you want to have a loop running and then execute a function when a key is pressed?  Or do you want your program to wait and continue after a key press?

Comment: Keypress detection is platform specific.  What platform (computer and OS) are you targeting?

Comment: What you describe should work. The problem is caused by your implementation. Please post the relevant source code.

Comment: I want to have loop running and then execute a function when a key is pressed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/kbhit?view=vs-2019) **_kbhit**.

You can also Refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15603082/how-to-use-kbhit-and-getch-c-programming) a stackoverflow answer.
**_kbhit** returns a nonzero value if a key has been pressed. Otherwise, it returns 0.
You can use this to enter your function optionally.

Please specify your operating System. This is for **Windows**.

For **Unix** like Operating System refer [this.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29335758/using-kbhit-and-getch-on-linux)

And If you are referring to and embedded System, Then please elaborate your question and add more details.